# Converting large dataframe to nd.array, doing spearman corr

Tags: pandas, correlation, numpy-ndarray

I have a large data consists of samples as index and names as header (500 X 30000).
eg:

```
          Name1    Name2    Name3
Sample1   232.12   0.239    -0.324
Sample2   0.928    23.213   -0.056
Sample3   -0.231   7.7776   -0.984
```

What I am trying to get:

```
          Name1    Name2    Name3
Name1      1        0.001    corr val
Name2      corr val   1      corr val
Name3      corr val  corr val   1
```

etc..

I thought about:

```
np.corrcoef(data)
```

But it's "pearsons" only and also I am getting an error claiming the data to large.

I tried splitting it

```
lst = []
data = For_spearman.to_numpy()
#data = np.delete(data, (0), axis=0)
data_size = len(data)-1
for key1 in range(1, data_size): #Ignoring first column which is index
    if key1 != data_size-1: # Cant compare after the last row, so -1 and -1.
        for key2 in range(key1+1 ,data_size): # Comparing name1 vs name2
            test = scipy.stats.spearmanr(data[key1][1:], data[key2][1:])
            lst .append([data[key1][0], data[key2][0], test])
            pd.DataFrame(lst ).to_csv('ForSpearman.csv')
```

But I just getting a mess as I am always getting tangled by nd.array somehow..
How can I do "np.corrcoef" job but in "spearman" way and splitting it so it will compare an array to another array each time ?

Comment: Is it `df.corr(method='spearman')`?

Comment: Yes for dataframe, but if I will do it I will get an error: ValueError: array is too big; arr.size * arr.dtype.itemsize is larger than the maximum possible size.

Comment: [Download more RAM](https://www.bing.com/search?pc=U523&q=download+more+ram&form=U523DF) :D

Comment: haha even with my desktop , which has 16, I couldn't ran it (edited, what's data's actual size)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's your problem, you are trying to create a 30000 x 30000 matrix, which alone is 7.2GB. 16GB might not be sufficient for intermediate arrays. One way though, is to loop. It will be slow but probably doable on your system:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(500, 30000))

out = pd.DataFrame(index=df.columns, columns = df.columns)

# you can also loop in chunks of columns
for col in df:
    out[col] = df.corrwith(df[col], method='spearman')
```

---

**Update**: The following might be less memory requirement

```
out = pd.concat([df.corrwith(df[col], method='spearman')
                   .to_frame(name=col) for col in df.columns],
                 axis=1)
```

Nevertheless, I think 12~16GB is pretty limited in this case. Also, looping would take forever.

Comment: Currently on my laptop, 12 gb, closed all apps, same error: ValueError: array is too big; `arr.size * arr.dtype.itemsize` is larger than the maximum possible size.

Comment: Thank you, this one is running (for now :) ). ahm.. yea  it's a little limited that's why I moved to work with nd.array but it was a mess

Comment: Now that I think about it, the second one might be worse because it would duplicate the final data. If you are writing things to the disk, you can write row by row with `append` mode.