# Spearman scipy states, on large data

Tags: python, memory, correlation

I was asking a similar quesiton on
[Converting large dataframe to nd.array, doing spearman corr](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65908078/converting-large-dataframe-to-nd-array-doing-spearman-corr)
but this one is a little different:
I am trying to compare one column to a big data set (30k). This time I am trying to get a "pvalue" in addition to the Rho value.
It can be done by:

```
stats.spearmanr(df,df['col'])
```

But this one is to large for my pc to run (memory error)

```
df= df[df.columns].apply(lambda x: x.corr(df['col'],method = 'spearman'))
```

This code gives only the Rho value

How can I use stats.spearmanr in a "lighter" way? (running currently on 12gb ram)

[rho = 0.4853049 , pval  = 0.923423..]
and so on

Comment: I doubt that calculating the correlation of 2 series with 30K entries will be problematic for 12GB ram...   can you give a working example of what you're trying to achieve here?

Comment: The series is working but it prints only rho, and I need pvalue too, which is achievable only with stats.spearmanr, edited.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**update**

this does the trick much more compact and equally well:

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from scipy.stats import spearmanr

idx = np.linspace(1, 100, 1000000)
# some random dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame(data=dict(x=np.sin(idx), 
                            y=np.tan(idx)**3,
                            z=np.cos(idx)), 
                  index=idx)

corrs = df.apply(lambda x: pd.Series(spearmanr(x, df.x)._asdict()))
```

**- - - - - -  OLD answer  - - - - - - -**

I guess it could help if you don't calculate the full correlation matrix, but just the values you're interested in...
(after all the matrix you're getting is symmetric and has `1` in the diagonal so the additional info is negligible...)

here's some code that has no problem with a dataframe of 1 (or even 10M) entries on my 16Gb ram laptop...

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from scipy.stats import spearmanr


idx = np.linspace(1, 100, 1000000)

# some random dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame(data=dict(x=np.sin(idx), 
                            y=np.tan(idx)**3,
                            z=np.cos(idx)), 
                  
                  index=idx)


def corr_with_col(df, var='x'):
    corrs = dict()

    for key, val in df.items():
        if key != var:
            corrs[f'{key}_{var}'] = spearmanr(df[var], df[key])
    
    return corrs

corrs = corr_with_col(df, 'x')

print('\n'.join([f'{key}: {val.correlation} ({val.pvalue})' 
                 for key, val in corrs.items()]))
```

```
>>> y_x: -0.004591765709253266 (4.394727211467625e-06)
>>> z_x: -0.0036273289997811407 (0.0002863601059399195)
```